# How can I catch which program turned num lock off?

Tags: windows, monitoring, numlock

I use Windows 10. I want to keep num lock on, but from time to time, I see it somehow got turned off. How can I catch which program is turning off num lock?

Comment: Is this computer an Acer?

Comment: @harrymc MSI laptop with an external keyboard attached to it

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to identify such a process.
You will need to write a program that will globally hook
the Windows API call
[SetKeyboardState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setkeyboardstate)
to find the process that is calling it for unsetting NumLock.
Writing this program is not a simple matter, but maybe you
could get some help at our sister forum
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Otherwise, you could workaround this problem in a simpler
way by writing a script, in PowerShell or other, that will
poll the state of NumLock in a loop and turn it back on
immediately if it's turned off.